# JQuery html() function not working correctly with table

Tags: jquery, html-table

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log($('#list_table_template').html());
    });
</script>

<div id="list_table_template" style="display: none;">
    <table id="list_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <p>123</p>
        <tr id="lt_header">
            <!--#lt_header#-->
        </tr>
        <!--#lt_listing#-->
        <tr id="lt_footer">
            <td colspan="5">Footer Placeholder</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This code is not returning expecting result.

While I was expecting log shows:

```
    <table id="list_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <p>123</p>
        <tr id="lt_header">
            <!--#lt_header#-->
        </tr>
        <!--#lt_listing#-->
        <tr id="lt_footer">
            <td colspan="5">Footer Placeholder</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

but instead it gives me:

```
<p>123</p><table id="list_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <tbody><tr id="lt_header">
        <!--#lt_header#-->
    </tr>
    <!--#lt_listing#-->
    <tr id="lt_footer">
        <td colspan="5">Footer Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Note the p tag is out of order and jump in front of the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't nest a paragraph inside a table unless it's inside a `<th>` or `<td>` tag. It's invalid HTML, so your browser relocates it outside the table, and jQuery can only read what the browser has parsed.

The best solution might be to replace the `p` with a [`caption`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption), which is valid HTML. However, if you want the paragraph to appear inside the table, you need to wrap it in `<tr><td>`...`</td></tr>` first.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser can't parse a `<p>`-tag inside of a `<table>`. So instead it will be parsed outsise of it.